# stop VNC from "Rect too big"

Tags: crash, vnc, remote-access

I use VNC to connect to a remote machine, but quite frequently the client crashes with the error "Rect too big". it's really annoying :/ why does it happen? is there a fix/workaround? I'm using TigerVNC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does it happen?

There is [an issue with ZRLE implementation](http://www.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2004-October/047502.html).

> is there a fix/workaround?

Use Hextile. Although RealVNC should have this bug fixed now, you may want to use it instead of TightVNC.